# How to schedule tasks with Celery in Django based on a model field and update them dynamically?

Tags: django, celery, task, scheduling

I've encountered a challenge while developing an application with Django and using Celery to schedule tasks based on a model field. I'd like to share my solution and seek advice on potential improvements. As a relatively inexperienced developer, I welcome any guidance.

I'm working on a Django application for managing training courses, and I need to schedule tasks when a registration deadline is reached. I've implemented Celery for task scheduling and store task IDs in a model field to allow for revocation if necessary.My challenge is ensuring that when the registration deadline is changed, the scheduled task is also updated or executed if the deadline has passed.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Training
from .tasks import post_registration_deadline


def delay_and_assign_registration_deadline_task(training_id):
    """
    The post_registration_deadline notifies the members of the training manager group if the minimum number of
    candidates is not reached. If there is still some registrations to review, they are canceled with the reason
    "REGISTRATION_DEADLINE_PASSED".
    """
    training = get_object_or_404(Training, id=training_id)
    task_id = post_registration_deadline.delay(training.id).task_id
    training.registration_deadline_task = task_id
    training.save()

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Training)
def pre_save_training(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.type.registration_enabled:

        """
        if the training is already created, we check if the registration deadline has changed
        if it has, we revoke the previous task. If the new deadline is now or before, we execute the task.
        If not, we schedule it for the new deadline date.
        """

        if instance.pk:
            previous = get_object_or_404(Training, id=instance.id)

            if previous.registration_deadline != instance.registration_deadline:
                task = AsyncResult(str(getattr(instance, 'registration_deadline_task')))
                task.revoke()

                if instance.registration_deadline <= timezone.now().date():
                    transaction.on_commit(lambda: delay_and_assign_registration_deadline_task(instance.id))
                else:
                    eta_time = datetime.combine(
                        instance.registration_deadline, 
                        datetime.max.time(), 
                        tzinfo=timezone.utc
                    )
                    instance.registration_deadline_task = post_registration_deadline.apply_async(
                        eta=eta_time, args=[instance.id]
                    ).task_id


@receiver(post_save, sender=Training)
def post_save_training(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    if, at training creation, the registration deadline is today or before, we start the
    post_registration_deadline_task if not, we schedule it for the registration deadline date.
    """

    if created:
        if instance.type.registration_enabled:

            if instance.registration_deadline <= timezone.now().date():
                transaction.on_commit(lambda: delay_and_assign_registration_deadline_task(instance.id))
            else:
                eta_time = datetime.combine(
                     instance.registration_deadline, 
                     datetime.max.time(), 
                     tzinfo=timezone.utc
                )
                instance.registration_deadline_task = post_registration_deadline.apply_async(
                    eta=eta_time, args=[instance.id]
                ).task_id


@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Training)
def pre_delete_training(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    registration_deadline_task = AsyncResult(str(getattr(instance, 'registration_deadline_task')))
    registration_deadline_task.revoke()
```